# SQL Where clause parameter faster than string literal. How do I fix?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, parameter-sniffing

Created following script to load user accounts.  Used a parameter string for username in initial testing in management studio.  Odd thing is after I changed from parameter string to string literal the query slowed down by 20 seconds.  Isn't it the other way usually for parameter sniffing?  I've tried DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and creating a stored procedure with setting some local vars, but that didn't speed up the query.  Any suggestions?

```
DECLARE @accntRep VARCHAR(50)
SET @accntRep = 'someUserName'

SELECT  accntRep,transBalance FROM companyView AS cv
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN pastdue > 0 THEN balance ELSE 0 END) AS pastDueBalance,
      SUM(balance) AS transBalance FROM pastDueView WHERE compID = cv.compID
    ) AS balance
WHERE 
--  accntRep = @accntRep   
accntRep = 'someUserName'
GROUP BY accntRep,transBalance
```

Comment: Rebuilding Index worked.  I feel a little silly.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a string literal and a local variable is usually an issue of stats where using a local variable uses an average distribution. So if the average is better than the actual stats (assuming an index does exist on the `[accntRep]` field) then it sounds like your statistics are out of date. At the very least update stats. Or you can do a REBUILD of the index which, as long as the index is not partitioned, will include a stats update `WITH FULLSCAN` (prior to SQL Server 2012, partitioned indexes also received the full stats update).

Comment: rebuilding Index worked.  Should have checked that first.  Thank you for your assistance.  Since the index was just rebuilt Sunday, I didn't think to try that.